# Inconsistency when switching between development to live server?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, relative-path

I always have trouble when moving a site that I've developed in localhost into my hosting server with the [`.htaccess`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) file. Specifically with relative paths to the files. It's not hard to fix, but it's quite bothering.

For example:

- Whereas `ErrorDocument 404 /foo/404.php` works in the
  hosting, for it to work in localhost I have to specify `ErrorDocument
  404 /projectroot/foo/404.php`.
- When using [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), `RewriteRule ^example/$ example.php [L,NC]`
  works in localhost, but for it to work in the hosting I must use
  `RewriteRule ^example/$ /example.php [L,NC]` (note the slash before the file name).

It *could* be because I'm running localhost on Windows and my hosting is on Linux, but I don't think that's the problem.

So my question is, how can I ensure the paths to the files are correct when working locally or on the remote server? What is the "working directory" for the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may look slight more complicated then it seems, but I would work out your issue in the following way.

1. Create a dev domain on the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file pointing to the IP 127.0.0.1 which is the localhost IP.

   The domain name doesn't really matter just something easy for you to use for that given project for example `test.dev` so the hosts file would look like this:

   ```
   # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
   #   127.0.0.1       localhost
   #   ::1             localhost
   127.0.0.1   localhost
   127.0.0.1   test.dev
   127.0.0.1   www.test.dev
   ```
2. Now define where the folder for that project will be, I will use `c:\projects\test` for this example.
3. Now create on your web server a new `virtualhost` for the domain you have just created, here is a sample of `virtualhost` that I use:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerAdmin root@localhost
           DocumentRoot "C:/projects/test"
           ServerName test.dev
           ServerAlias www.test.dev
           ErrorLog "C:/projects/logs/test.dev_error_log"
           CustomLog "C:/projects/logs/test.dev_access_log" common
           RewriteLog "C:/projects/logs/test.dev_rewrite_log"
           RewriteLogLevel 9
           ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/projects/test/cgi-bin/"

           <Directory "C:/projects/test">
                   Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
                   AllowOverride All
                   Order allow,deny
                   Allow from all
           </Directory>
           <Directory "C:/projects/test/cgi-bin">
                   AllowOverride None
                   Options None
                   Order allow,deny
                   Allow from all
           </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. Restart your server to activate the changes, you do not need to restart the computer for the hosts file, it should work immediately once you save it.
5. Now you can use `http://www.test.dev` or `http://test.dev` and you can use the very same `.htaccess` on both, dev and live sites.

---

Some other tips:

1. Always use and define `RewriteBase /` as it can make a difference specially when you want to use rules without the `/` at the start, like you have mentioned for `RewriteRule ^example/$ example.php [L,NC]`
2. Depending on the rules you want to use, you may need to specify `-MultiViews` so I often just leave it on by default, like this:

   ```
   Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
   ```
3. As you can see on my `virtualhost` setup, I define the access, error and rewrite logs into the logs folder by default and with the domain name in question so when I need to see what is going on I have an easy access with the clear logs for that domain only and not my whole bunch of projects running on the same `virualhost`.

I guess that is about it, you don't really need that huge `virtualhost` that's just how I use it and its not like I need to copy and paste it all the time as I have my own simple script to create new domains and do all the work for me.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer man! It was indeed more complicated that I thought it was. I'll use your hosts file pointing and virtualhost setup so I don't have to change the `htaccess` file every time I upload my project to the hosting.