# how to configuring a xampp web server for different root directory

Tags: php, apache, webserver, xampp

The web directory is the home of all of your application's public and static files. Including images, stylesheets and JavaScript files. It is also where the front controllers live.

So the question is when i install and set up xampp my web directory is:

```
xampp\htdocs
```

and I want to set it up for:

```
xampp\htdocs\myproject\web
```

How to do it?
Now when I type in my browser the address: `http://localhost/`
I enter `xampp\htdocs` directory
and I want to  type in my browser the address: `http://localhost/`
and enter `xampp\htdocs\myproject\web` directory

Comment: You can use my answer over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862739/inconsistency-when-switching-between-development-to-live-server/18863056#18863056 by creating a separated virtualhost you can define different root directories for different projects and by using the hosts file you can make new local domains.

Comment: what about that virtualhost file ?
its virtualhost.file or what type it is ?

Comment: that is usually placed inside the file named `vhosts.conf` but in some cases can also be placed at the end of `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 185, accepted):

You can change Apaches httpd.conf by clicking (in xampp control panel) `apache/conf/httpd.conf` and adjust the entries for `DocumentRoot` and the corresponding `Directory` entry.
Just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for "htdocs" and change the entries to your new path.

See screenshot:

[image: XAMPP config]

```
#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
```

Comment: Can it be any arbitrary directory? Even on a different partition?

Comment: @posfan12, I'm a little late to the game here, but since it uses a fully qualified path, you can put it on a different drive entirely. Or might even be able to put it on a mapped network drive, too, depending on your network speed.

Answer (score 54):

- Go to  C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
- Open httpd.conf
- Find tag : DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
- Edit tag to :  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/web"
- Now find tag  and change it to < Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/web" >
- Restart Your Apache

Comment: It does works for a single project but what for multiple ones ?

Comment: I'm a little late to the game here, but I would suggest against setting `DocumentRoot` to a specific folder inside "htdocs". If you simply have a folder inside "htdocs", you can point your browser to "localhost/myproject/web" or "localhost/mysecondproject"  (or whatever folder you created) to have it work for multiple websites.

Answer (score 26):

In case, if anyone prefers a simpler solution, especially on Linux (e.g. Ubuntu), a very easy way out is to create a symbolic link to the intended folder in the htdocs folder. For example, if I want to be able to serve files from a folder called "/home/some/projects/testserver/" and my htdocs is located in "/opt/lampp/htdocs/". Just create a symbolic link like so:

```
ln -s /home/some/projects/testserver /opt/lampp/htdocs/testserver
```

The command for symbolic link works like so: 
     `ln -s target source`
where,

```
target - The existing file/directory you would like to link TO.
source - The file/folder to be created, copying the contents of the target. The LINK itself.
```

For more help see ln --help 
Source: [Create Symbolic Links in Ubuntu](http://ubuntuhak.blogspot.fi/2013/04/symbolic-links-in-ubuntu.html)

And that's done. just visit http://localhost/testserver/
In fact, you don't even need to restart your server.

Comment: This is the best! Easy and completely flexible. Thanks.

Comment: This is great, and on Windows it would be `mklink /J source target`

Comment: Perfect, easiest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

I moved my htdocs folder from C:\xampp\htdocs to D:\htdocs without editing the Apache config file (httpd.conf).

Step 1) Move `C:\xampp\htdocs` folder to `D:\htdocs`
Step 2) Create a symbolic link in C:\xampp\htdocs linked to D:\htdocs using mklink command.

```
D:\>mklink /J C:\xampp\htdocs D:\htdocs
Junction created for C:\xampp\htdocs <<===>> D:\htdocs

D:\>
```

Step 3) Done!

Answer (score 10):

ok guys you are not going to believe me how easy it is, so i putted a video on YouTube to show you that [ [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFZLGNiN0Ok) ]

now , 
steps :

1. run your xampp control panel
2. click the button saying config
3. select apache( httpd.conf )
4. find document root
5. replace

`DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">`

those 2 lines  || C:/xampp/htdocs == current location for root || change C:/xampp/htdocs with any location you want

6. save it
   DONE: start apache and go to the localhost 
   see in action [ [watch video click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFZLGNiN0Ok) ]

Answer (score 7):

You can also put in a new virtual Host entry in the

> c:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd-vhosts.conf

like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/web"
  ServerName localhost
  ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
  CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: When used `httpd-vhosts.conf` make sure it's included (uncommented) in the `XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf` file

Answer (score 4):

```
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
```

Write above code inside following tags    < Directory "c:\projects" > < / Directory >
c:(you can add any directory d: e:) is drive where you have created your project folder.

Alias /projects "c:\projects"

Now you can access the pr0jects directory on your browser :

localhost/projects/

Answer (score 2):

If you are running **xampp on linux** based image, to change root directory open:

```
/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf
```

Change default document root: 
    `DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs" and <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs"`

to your folder `DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/myFolder" and <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/myFolder">`

Answer (score 2):

For XAMMP versions >=7.5.9-0 also change the DocumentRoot in file "/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-ssl.conf" accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the port while you open your XAMP control panel, follow the steps:

1. click on config net to the start button, and
2. select `httpd.conf`,  a text file will open
3. check the file and file `listen:80`,
4. once got `listen:80` replace with `listen:8080` and
5. save in the same folder.

Once done that, you will be able to start your local server.

Comment: this is not about changing the port.