# Where's httpd.conf after setting up PHP environment with XAMPP?

Tags: php, apache

I set up the PHP environment with XAMPP on Mac. I want to change the default web directory to my workspace. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902887/how-to-configuring-a-xampp-web-server-for-diffrent-root-directory) and it did help.

But my question is where the `httpd.conf` is placed?

I found one under `/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/conf`, but it's not same as what I opened from XAMPP manager.

Then where's the `httpd.conf` opened from XAMPP manager? And what's the relationship and difference between these two `httpd.conf`?

Comment: You mean [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) as in _httpd_.conf?

Comment: No, I mean `php.ini`.

Comment: `<?php echo get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');` will print the path to the php.ini. But there's no DocumentRoot directive ini `php.ini`s. DocumentRoot is a httpd directive. see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Comment: @VolkerK Sorry, I just found that it's httpd.conf, that's why I didn't find it.  I'm new to php. It's really embarrassing. Let me check again.

Comment: Do you know where's the `httpd.conf`, I found one under `xamppfiiles/apache2/conf`, but seems it's not the right one.

Comment: `xamppfiiles/apache2/conf` sounds right to me. There can be [INCLUDE](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include) directives in the httpd.conf. E.g. https-hosts are sometimes configured in another .conf file which is then included into the "main" httpd.conf.

Comment: Alias /bitnami/ "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
This is the content of `httpd.conf` under `xmappfiles/apache2/conf`, no INCLUDE found.

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) the default value of DocumentRoot is `/usr/local/apache/htdocs`

Comment: Yes, I just want to change it to my workspace.

Comment: Then just add a DocumentRoot directive.

Comment: Yes, I changed the value of `DocumentRoot` to my own folder, but it shows `Access forbidden!` when I'm accessing `localhost`. Do you know what's going on?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with file system permissions. Your httpd process has no access to your ~home directory (or subdir).

Comment: I've changed it to folder `Developer` and tried to change the mode to 777, and it didn't work.