# Move index.php to subfolder and redirect page to this folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

I want move index.php to a subfolder of the project in xampp, for example

localhost/project redirect to localhost/project/subfolder where I have index.php

What rule must I overwrite in htaccess?
My idea was try to see if I could make this change editing specifically in htaccess.

Thanks

Comment: What is your current rule in htaccess that you want to overwrite?
Explain your issue a bit more detailed, with quick googling your solution may be found here: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Transparently_redirect_your_root_directory_to_a_subdirectory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to configuring a xampp web server for diffrent root directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902887/how-to-configuring-a-xampp-web-server-for-diffrent-root-directory)

Comment: Well, The solution that I found googling was this... in htaccess

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ Folder/index.php...

and it worked. I moved index.php the root directory to subdirectory and later I couldn't load the main page. Thanks for the comment