# Relative path in a HTML file

Tags: html, css, relative-path

I have the following folder structure tree (folder names are written in uppercase letters):

```
ONLINESHOP
    |-- index.html
    |-- COMPONENTS
    |-- CONFIG
    |-- TEMPLATES
        |-- CSS
            |-- main-style.css
    |-- CONTROLLERS
    |-- MODELS
    |-- VIEWS
       ...
       |-- USER
           |-- login.html
```

So the root folder is OnlineShop. I am trying to reach `main-style.css` from `login.html`

This works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/OnlineShop/templates/css/main-style.css">
```

And this doesn't:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/templates/css/main-style.css">
```

My question: why doesn't the later code work? Isn't `/` supposed to bring me to the root folder (OnlineShop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the web application root depends on your server configuration.

As an alternative you can use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../templates/css/main-style.css">
```

Comment: Oh, I'm using XAMPP Apache Server, would that mean that the root folder is htdocs (that would make sense for me then)?

Comment: Please check this question then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902887/how-to-configuring-a-xampp-web-server-for-diffrent-root-directory

Comment: Thank you, I will keep researching in the right direction now!