# Can I create my project other than in htdocs

Tags: php, html

I am using xamp to buld my web project. It seems like I can only create my project inside the htdocs folder.Can I create the project other than in htdocs?

Comment: That's just the default, it can be changed in apache configuration

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902887/how-to-configuring-a-xampp-web-server-for-different-root-directory

Comment: No, But you can create any number of  folders inside htdocs folder