# src="/img/test.jpg" works online but doesn't in localhost

Tags: javascript, html

in goDaddy hosting i worked all the urls like this

```
img src="/img/resources/yyyy.jpg"
```

but right now im working in local mode with xampp and doesnt work until i change the url to this

```
img src="img/resources/yyyy.jpg
```

when i finished the project in goDaddy hosting every url i write i done it with the "/" at first

but right now with xampp in local mode i have to remove the "/" to make it work again

and i dont want to change every url of my project its a lot of work

Comment: What root folder is being served locally?

Comment: not quite sure what are you asking but i use the default xampp folder htdocs
C:\xampp\htdocs\BG\public_html\index.php i downloaded the project from godaddy and i put it right there

Comment: Where is the img folder relative to index.php? What does the local url look like?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\BG\public_html\img\resources\yyyy.jpg the img folder is in the same place of index.php and i use the local url like this http://127.0.0.1/BG/public_html/index.php in google chrome in the code src="img/resources/yyyy.jpg>"

Comment: right, then you probably need to change the root. It's currently two directories too high

Comment: thanks ill try it right now

Comment: man you can go to heaven it work it perfectly give the answer i make it correct and give you 1+

Comment: would you say https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902887/how-to-configuring-a-xampp-web-server-for-different-root-directory is the answer?

Comment: i just put the project in the htdocs C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php and it works as you said it it was two directories high its working perfectly thanks for that