# The requested URL was not found on this server with Codeigniter3

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have an application with codeigniter, I want to call a Home controller when the application view is in the Contacts menu, but an error appears like this

[image]

> **Link URL**

```
<li><a href="<?= base_url('home');?>" class="active">Beranda</a></li>
```

> **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Are other CI URLs working OK?

Answer (score 0):

Make .htaccess file in your root directory using below code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: tried it, still the same

Comment: I think your application/config.php file has a problem.

$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/Your Ci folder_name';

Comment: "tried it, still the same" - Because, basically, it is the same! (This is not a `.htaccess` issue.) @labkes

Comment: this is the common mistake, you may check first the path or see this reference

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902887/how-to-configuring-a-xampp-web-server-for-different-root-directory