# 403 Forbidden Error when accessing any file or path

Tags: xampp, http-status-code-403

I know there are so many answers to this error, but none of it works.
In XAMPP Windows Version 8.2.12 I tried to make a form with HTML, CSS, and PHP.
I wanted to do that locally so I installed PHP, XAMPP, and MariaDB (Side note, MariaDB is not yet configured).
My Error is so weird that I didn't find any solution to it. Any solution to that error is the same.
ChatGPT has 0 clue.
If I access any file through localhost:80/ it will ALWAYS give me the error 403 Access forbidden. Even when accessing a file that doesn't even exist on my PC.
Error logs? Nothing. Doesn't show a single error that could lead to the problem.
The 3 only files that work are the dashboard, phpMyAdmin, and phpinfo.

Already tried to configure a vHost.
Edited the httpd.conf and gave the server every right to access any file and path in my project folder.
Tried to put my Project file into the htdocs folder.
Looked up any possible Stackoverflow question with the same error.

Please help I'm gettin' frustrated.

Comment: slowly. uninstall xampp. reinstall it, and set the directory to be a folder on your desktop. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31901690/4935162). then, create an html file in that folder named `index.html`, write 'test' inside. restart xampp. try to go to `http://localhost`.

Comment: @Yarin_007 I didn't mentioned it, but i already tried that. It still gave me 403.

Comment: that is strange indeed. try with [wamp](https://www.wampserver.com/en/) and see if anything changes. be sure to stop xampp before launching wamp as by default they will both try to listen on the same ports (80 & 443). oh btw, maybe before that, make sure only one instance of the server is running. maybe reboot too.

Comment: @Yarin_007 I didn‘t follow your last advice (will do it afterwards). Everytime I open up a localhost page, the Windows Event Viewer gives me the error „„Autopilot.dll WIL-Error was reported“ HRESULT: 0x80070491 Return NULL“

Comment: uhhh, i really don't think that's related. any luck with wamp?

Comment: @Yarin_007 weird things going on right now. Just installed WAMP and restarted my PC. Opened WAMP and then XAMPP. Apache just disappeared. It gives me the error „apache shutdown unexpectedly.“. I just checked and in the XAMPP folder there is no damn apache folder anymore. How!?

Comment: @Yarin_007 I just reinstalled Apache and now everything works. I’m not getting any 403 Screens anymore. 
Still thanks for your time!