# htaccess subdirectory as root directory

Tags: .htaccess

I know there is a few questions like this here, so forgive me for not being able to piece this together - I want a subdirectory (mainsite) to display when someone visits the root only, while the rest of the site remains as normal.

structure is:

```
www.mysite.com
  --globalcss
  --sites--mainsite--index.php
                   --anotherpage.php
                   --css--style.css
         --anothersite
         --anothersite
```

I'm also trying to get the relative css links on the mainsite index page (../../globalcss/global.css) to work once the mainsite index is displaying in the root. At one point I had the page working, but the css links were incorrectly showing as `sites/mainsite/globalcss/`, ignoring the `../../` (I'd rather keep them relative if possible as my localhost root doesn't match).

Here is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
# attempting to get only requests in the root directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(sites|globalcss)
# show the mainsite content instead
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/mainsite/$1 [L]
```

Thanks

Comment: [I would highly recommend you to change it into something like this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862739/inconsistency-when-switching-between-development-to-live-server/18863056#18863056) This way you will have a closer version of what you have on your live server, will have an alias domain to work with and won't have the above issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Prix, but I'm running dropbox with one instance of xampp across multiple pc's. The benifit of syncing outweighs the issues I have with that at the moment.

Comment: You don't need several instances of XAMP you can do that with a single instance, all it takes is the addition of new virtualhost's to the `vhosts.conf` or `httpd.conf` file depending on how it is configured.

Answer (score 1):

So by "someone visits the root only", I assume you mean `http://www.mysite.com/`, and not `http://www.mysite.com/anotherpage.php`. If that's the case then:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !globalcss
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/mainsite
RewriteRule ^$ /sites/mainsite/ [L]
```

If you're actually referring to anything that isn't a subdirectory, as in: `http://www.mysite.com/` is ok, `http://www.mysite.com/a-file.php` is ok, but `http://www.mysite.com/css/` should not be rewritten, then the rule needs to look like:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /sites/mainsite/$1 [L]
```

and everything else is the same.

The way that you have your regex setup:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/mainsite/$1 [L]
```

rewrites everything except "globalcss". And that doesn't seem to jive at all with your request that "while the rest of the site remains as normal."

---

> only thing is my sites/mainsite/css is now not working, as it is looking relative to the root, not original location. How can I work around this? I also have a js folder there too, which I assume has the same issue

The browser looks relative to the root because that's all it knows. All it knows is *"I go here: `http://mysite.com/` and I see link `"css/some_file.css"`*, So the only thing it can do is go to `http://mysite.com/css/some_file.css`, the browser knows nothing of all these rewrites or aliases which exists only on the server.

If you want css to be able to get accessed, then you need a rule for that as well (this is really a terrible, terrible way of doing all of this):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !globalcss
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/mainsite/css
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /sites/mainsite/css/$1 [L]
```

Probably something similar to js also

Comment: This works (top section), only thing is my sites/mainsite/css is now not working, as it is looking relative to the root, not original location. How can I work around this? I also have a js folder there too, which I assume has the same issue.

Comment: @John all depends on how you're linking, the browser doesn't know what's going on on the server, it just sees HTML and sends the request

Comment: The last rewrite rule didn't work, but adding this did: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^css/(.*)$`. Now I'm having the same issue with the images folder in the same directory. How can I add that, tried the same thing, adding another line and swapping 'css' for 'images', but no luck. I think because images has subfolders itself. Is there a way I can condense one rule to exclude: images|js|css|php subfolders?