# .htaccess mod_rewrite does not work with two parameters on localhost

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I would like to have clean URLs in my projects. So I've written these codes in a .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On  
Options +FollowSymLinks  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [NC,QSA,L]  
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

But it does not work completely when I'm trying to work with it locally.
Imagine that I have a directory `myproject` in htdocs (www) in my local web server path and other files are stored in this folder. Now I can see the project if I go to `localhost/project`.

Now I want to work with URLs.
It works well if I have only one parameter in URI like `localhost/myproject/tours`. But if I have 2 parameters like `localhost/myprojects/tours/inside`, it seems that all css, js and images files go away. I've also added `RewriteBase /myproject` to .htaccess file, but nothing solved.

What is my mistake? I need a solution that works on both remote and local server.

Comment: Why not make virtualhost with wildcard that will automatically make any folder inside the root of myproject a unique project with a unique domain like `test.myproject`, `projectb.myproject`, etc instead of localhost? You can also change myproject to any name you see fit easily. [Here is an example with no wildcards but you can easily implement.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862739/inconsistency-when-switching-between-development-to-live-server/18863056#18863056)

Comment: @Prix I'm seeking a way inside .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, see my response on your other question about your code: [Why .htaccess mod_rewrite does not show a real directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265844/why-htaccess-mod-rewrite-does-not-show-a-real-directory/22267944#22267944)

Now, `RewriteBase` won't solve your problem about css/js/images etc. It's only for htaccess and it defines the base path when a rule is rewritten.

One common way to avoid this problem is to add in all your files a base url right after `<head>` html tag.
For you, it would be: `<base href="http://localhost/myproject/" />`

Otherwise, if you reach `localhost/myprojects/tours/inside` then your css/js/images *links* will be resolved as `localhost/myprojects/tours/inside/__here__` because the default base path here is the current directory (`/myproject/tours/inside/`) and this is not what you want

Edit: if that's the case, don't forget to remove leading slashes from your css/images/javascript html links

Comment: it does not work even with one parameter now. I don't know why. I've changed .htaccess file as you said in my next question (Solution 1).

Comment: Did you add `RewriteBase /myprojects/` right after `RewriteEngine on` ? Also, what do you mean by `it does not work` ? Are you getting an http error or still display issue with css/js/images ?

Comment: I've tested it with `RewriteBase` and without it. Also with `<base>` and without it. but the problem is still css/js/images issues

Comment: Well the right way is to take my code from other question (solution 1) and add `RewriteBase /myproject/` right after `RewriteEngine on` (don't forget to rename `myproject` by the real name). Then, you have to add `<base href="http://localhost/myproject/" />` (don't forget to rename here too) right after `<head>` html tag in **every concerned pages**. Finally, your css/images/js html links must not begin with a `/`. After that, this should work

Comment: All css,js, and images started with `/`. Even if I write `RewriteBase /myproject` and `<base href="http://localhost/myproject" />`, I have to omit `/` from start of paths?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is not the same. You have to remove all leading slash `/` from your css/js/images html links and add `<base href="http://localhost/myproject/" />` (with a trailing slash). The same in your htaccess (`RewriteBase /myproject/` with a trailing slash). Also, keep in mind that `RewriteBase` is not directly related to your problem (it concerned htaccess only)

Comment: Thank you Justin, you won the award because of your valuable answer and solution

Answer (score 0):

The browser will build absolute URL paths out of your relative URL paths by looking at your made up context of /myprojects/tours.  You may need to strip one or two levels of that prefix off to find the real path.

The access log will show you plain as day what relative URL's come in when you use the old and new URLs.

Comment: where can I find access log?