# Why .htaccess mod_rewrite does not show a real directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

I've written the codes below inside a .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

I have made a control panel for administrator of my website inside **admin** directory too. The problem is that when I want to enter to control panel from this address `www.site.com/admin`, it does not show what I really want. After that, URL changes to `www.site.com/admin/?p=admin`.
What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditions are applied on following rule only.
Your second rule is evaluated even if it is an existing directory or file.

If your 2 rules must respect both conditions, you have 2 possibilities.

Duplicate your conditions:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

# this rule is evaluated if not a directory AND not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

# this rule is evaluated if not a directory AND not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Or simulate `if/else` condition by doing nothing if it's a directory/file

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

# if file or directory, leave (do nothing)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]

# if we reach here, means it's not a file or directory. So rules can be evaluated
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Also, this is not so important but you don't have to escape `.` when into square brackets: `([^/\.]+)` can be `([^/.]+)`

Comment: Thank you @Justin. Your first solution solved my problem. Second one failed!