# How to get project root directory URL?

Tags: php

I tried to get my project root directory using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but they give me `c:\xampp\htdocs`, after that I tried to use `_DIR_` but they give me `c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\myfile` but I need to get to this URL:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject
```

Thanks!

Comment: `realpath(__DIR__.'/../');`

Comment: That's because `c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject` was never a root folder to begin with. If you make a virtualhost for that project, then you can have `c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject` as root. [**Here is an example of how to make a virtualhost and how it could benefit you.**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862739/inconsistency-when-switching-between-development-to-live-server/18863056#18863056)