# How can I serve multiple sites with apache based on the URL

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have two separate Django projects that I want to serve up from the same machine. I'm trying to set up my VirtualHost configurations in apache to serve them up. I know I can serve them up on separate ports, but I'd rather do it based on the request URL. So `example.com/app1` would go to one app and `example.com/app2` would go to the other. ServerName and ServerAlias won't work since they only look at the Host, which in both cases would just be `example.com`. Is there any way to do this?

The ServerPath directive looked promising but it looks like, since it was only meant as a fallback for older browsers, apache only looks at ServerPath if the browser doesn't supply the Host field in the request.

**Update**: Here is what the VirtualHost configuration for my first app looks right now.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAlias *
  WSGIScriptAlias /app1 /home/eyuelt/app1/app1/wsgi.py
  Alias /app1/static /home/eyuelt/app1/staticfiles

  <Directory /home/eyuelt/app1/app1>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Order deny,allow
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  <Directory /home/eyuelt/app1/staticfiles>
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: [See this answer to have a local domain per project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18863056/342740)

Comment: Create two hosts on each folder = result you want. Or add more info about what you want (simple example).